# Remote log reporting for asp.net error svc.log?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a couple of asp.net applications and servers (prod, beta) running on different boxes that are tracing to different svc.logs.

What are recommendations regarding a remote web-based log viewer solution so that support personnel do not have to map a drive or login remotely to view the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should write log to a DB with fast writes, like MongoDB.

Then create an app that query this DB.

Not only you will centralize your log in a unique point, so it's easy to query; but you will also avoid extra load on the web server (for quering logs).

The web servers can simply send data in a push and forget way (message queuing can help to scale).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try [cloud4apps](https://www.cloud4apps.com) remote error logging service. It's really simple to use and allows for easy integration with any source. It runs on Microsoft cloud services and gives aggregated views to your logs and extensive reporting capabilities.